# Best Healing Potion Possible

Tags: pathfinder-1e, potions

I have built a lvl 20 fighter with the ability to chug potions/Drinks as a swift action. I don't remember how I got that power, but as best as I remember it applies to all drinkable substances. What are the best potions he can get with a dedicated budget of 100,000 gold (left after other gear)? He needs to be able to have multiple of potions and they need to heal as much as possible each round.

I have built this character to chug potions as a rule of cool and it is part of the personality and he is only meant to be a one off character who fights a member of our party.

As this is a lvl 20 character he will have the gold, resources and contacts needed to have just about any level caster of whatever specialty he needs to make the potion for him.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're limited to just potions, the very best you can do is a CL 15 potion of cure serious wounds. That would heal for 3d8+15, and cost 2250g. This is assuming you can find a level 15 caster to brew them for you.

However, if he has an alchemist friend with the Infusion discovery, and his ability allows him to drink extracts, then the best he could do is a CL 15 Heal extract, which would heal for 150. I'm not sure how you would price such an extract, but if you use the potion pricing rules, it would cost 4500g.

Comment: Gah! I was just about to submit the same answer. Average healing is 28.5 hp per potion.

Comment: +1, however on the first round or rounds where his HP are max, he might want to drink an 'infernal healing' potion instead (fast healing 1).

Comment: I'm not sure this is in the raw rules, but maybe you can use metamagic when creating potion to brew stronger one.

Comment: @Xasun any metamagic that would increase the healing such as empower or maximize would increase the spell's level beyond the cap of 3.

Comment: @EricB Contentious. Metamagic generally *doesn't* (excepting Heighten Spell) change the level of the spell, just the level of the spell slot used to cast it. Most interpret that as meaning that things that refer to a spell's level (*globe of invulnerability*, potion-making, etc.) use the unchanged level, though it is debatable. Unfortunately, abusive tricks are available for both interpretations. In my experience, treating metamagic'd spells as not spells of their level is more consistent and leads to less serious abuses.

Comment: Effects of Metamagic Feats on a Spell: In all ways, a metamagic spell operates at its original spell level, even though it is prepared and cast using a higher-level spell slot. Saving throw modifications are not changed unless stated otherwise in the feat description.

The modifications made by these feats only apply to spells cast directly by the feat user. A spellcaster can't use a metamagic feat to alter a spell being cast from a wand, scroll, or other device. http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats

Comment: @mxyzplk Doesn't entirely resolve the ambiguity. As it says, you cannot apply, say, Empower Spell to *potion of cure serious wounds*, but it doesn't exactly say that you cannot create a *potion of empowered cure serious wounds*, which... you arguably can, kind of. Still, the rules as written do given an opening for an interpretation that avoids almost all abuse (i.e. metamagic doesn't change the spell's level but can't be used for item-creation), and that is also most likely the intent, so... good point. That wording is different from what I'd remembered.

Comment: @KRyan I would like to mention the [Riffle Scroll](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/scroll-riffle) at this point, which states that "only spells that have been modified by the Silent Spell metamagic feat can be crafted into riffle scrolls" and that "[t]his affects the spell’s effective spell level for the purposes of determining the riffle scroll’s price." This gives a precedent to metamagiced spells being cast into use-activated items. Then again, if you could normally do that with regular scrolls, riffle scrolls would be entirely pointless.

Comment: @KRyan "**Magic Items and Metamagic Spells**: With the right item creation feat, you can store a metamagic version of a spell in a scroll, **potion**, or wand. Level limits for potions and wands apply to the spell's higher spell level (after the application of the metamagic feat). A character doesn't need the metamagic feat to activate an item storing a metamagic version of a spell." - http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats

Comment: An extract is arguably cheaper than the equivalent potion because it only lasts 24h.